Legendre coefficients of $|x|-1$
To compute the $0-$degree Legendre coefficient of $f(x)=|x|-1$ , $-1<x<1$ , with the formula $c_n=\frac{2n+1}{2}\int_{-1}^1 f(x)P_n(x)dx$ (where $P_n$ is the $n-$degree Legendre polynomial) I've got
$$c_0=\frac{2\cdot0+1}{2}\int_{-1}^1 (|x|-1)1 dx =\frac{1}{2}\cdot 2\int_{0}^1 (x-1) dx = \Big[\frac{1}{2}x^2-x\Big]_0^1=-\frac{1}{2}$$
but the solution says just $\frac{1}{2}$. Every other coefficient is correct so I think that it's the right procedure... I'm missing something here? Where does the missing (or extra) minus sign come from?

As a sanity check, note that $|x|-1/2$ averages to zero on [−1,1] and is thus orthogonal to $P_0(x)=1$. So $1/2$ is appropriate for $|x|$, but therefore $-1/2$ is appropriate for $|x|-1$ (to get $|x|-1-(-1/2)=|x|-1/2$). So this does indeed seem to be a mistake.
